# How to negative look ahead using vim/grep

Tags: regex, vim, grep

I was able to build my Regex on regxr.com

```
/.*GET.*(?!(Chrome)).*"$/
```

I want my regex to not match this line:

```
node_lum.log:C3 2019-04-15 15:00:28.954 NOTICE: 6ms 77.172.180.249 GET /users/zone/active.json?customer_name=hl_e5d4a218 HTTP/1.1 200 - - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"
```

And match this

```
node_lum.log:C3 2019-04-15 15:00:28.954 NOTICE: 6ms 77.172.180.249 GET /users/zone/active.json?customer_name=hl_e5d4a218 HTTP/1.1 200 - - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) asd/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"
```

I've tried using both vim and grep.

On vim, I tried

```
/*GET.*\(Chrome\)\@!.*"$
/*GET.*\(\(Chrome\)\)\@!.*"$
```

On grep, I tried

```
grep -P '.*GET.*(?!(Chrome)).*"$' ./grep.txt
grep -P '.*GET.*(?!Chrome).*"$' ./grep.txt
```

None of those got me the matches I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `grep`, you should remove the first `.*` (it is redundant) and make sure the next `.*` is inside the negative lookahead:

```
GET(?!.*Chrome).*"$
      ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tybTLS/1) and a [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=GET(%3F!.*Chrome).*%22%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `GET` - a `GET` substring
- `(?!.*Chrome)` - no `Chrome` is allowed after any 0+ chars other than line rbeak chars
- `.*"$` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and a `"` at the end of the line must be present.

In Vim, it will look like

```
GET\(.*Chrome\)\@!.*"$
```

The `\(.*Chrome\)\@!` is the negative lookahead equivalent.

Comment: its not working. `grep -P 'GET(?!.*ALALA).*"$' ./grep.txt`
there's not a single line with ALALA, so this should return the whole file, yet is retuning nothing

Comment: @iagowp If there is no match, you can't expect `grep` (a tool to extract only matching lines/substrings) to return you the whole file. If you need `sed`, use `sed`. But it does not support PCRE, so this pattern won't work.

Comment: thats a negative lookahead, so I'd be getting all lines that have GET and don't have ALALA. isn't all of them supposed to be matches?

Comment: `GET(?!.*Chrome)` will match a string `GET` that has no `Chrome` after it, to the right of the `GET` word. To make sure there is no `Chrome` anywhere on a line you need `^(?!.*Chrome).*GET`.

Comment: thats what I wanted, but I didn't think of it this way. Thanks